# Documentation for moderator tools

Tags: support, moderation

I'm looking for some documentation on the moderation tools.  I am aware of the [tools page](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/tools?tab=links), and I can see the various 'edit' and 'synonyms' links when I explore the site.

However, I really don't want to just poke around and break something.  I've seen a number of times where a user with new tag edits will start bumping all kinds of old questions to the front page for little grammar fixes, and I don't want to force a mod to go back into the database and undo something I screwed up. Where can I read up on when and how to use these abilities?

I feel like I'm learning how to use a terminal all over again.  I'm staring at a blinking prompt, wondering what to type.  `man [letters]` produces interesting things for some values of [letters], and those are all reasonably well documented, but that doesn't mean I know how to use the computer.  To learn the terminal, it's easy enough to set up a VM and poke around until something good or bad happens, but E&R isn't a VM.  It's a live system that affects a lot of people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, we are trying to make the tools self documenting. Which tools in particular did you need guidance on, what do you think those pages should say on them to help you?

Comment: The tools themselves are essentially self-documenting.  Read the caption, type in the box, click the button.  Pretty standard stuff.  However, for an example, I noticed that [max] and [msp] are separate tags, when they should be [max-msp], except for the [msp]+[msp430] questions.  What tools do I use for this modification?  When do I use the other options?  How should I monitor tag creation, and what should I do when I see something wrong?  I need a 'big picture' guide to the tools.

Comment: @reem I suggest the E&R chat room as a starting point http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15

Comment: @reemrevnivek, Yes, please feel free to come by the E&R chat room and let the other mods help you feel your way around. As @jeff has pointed out, the chat room can be a good place to come get help and guidance.